# Pointer and structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Given a structure *book* defined as follows and an array *lib* of struct book:

```
struct Book{
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    int price;
    struct Book *nextedition;
};


struct Book lib[1000];
```

I'm going to write a function to compute total price of books by a given author including all books which are future editions of his book, even if the author of that future edition is NOT the specified author.

```
   title    author  price   nextedition
----------------------------------
0  Book1    Author1 25      &lib[2]
1  Book2    Author2 20      NULL
2  Book3    Author3 30      &lib[3]
3  Book4    Author1 35      NULL
```

For the example above, the book at lib[2] is a next edition of that at lib[0], and the book at lib[4] is the next edition of that at lib[2]. Therefore given the author "Author1", the function should return 90 (=25+30+35), and given the author "Author 3", the function should return 65 (=30+35).

So this is my code:

```
int firstEdition(char author[100]){
    int i, pos=-1;
    for(i=0;i<numbooks;i++)
    if(strcmp(lib[i].author,author)==0){
        pos=i;
        if(pos>=0) return pos;
    }
    return -1;
}

int totalPrice(char author[100]){
    int price=0;
    int i=firstEdition(author);
    if (i<0)
        return 0;
    else {      
        while (lib[i].nextedition != NULL){
            price+=lib[i].price;
            lib[i]=*(lib[i].nextedition);
        }
    return price;}
}
```

I've tried running the code with the above example and author="Author1" and kept getting the wrong output. The function always returns `55` instead of `90`, and I can't seem to figure out why. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `totalPrice` exits its `while` loop before considering the price of the last book in a list.  It also changes some members of `lib` which isn't obviously desirable.

The following (untested) code should give you the correct `price` without changing the state of `lib`

```
int totalPrice(char author[100]){
    int price=0;
    int i=firstEdition(author);
    struct Book *book;
    if (i<0)
        return 0;
    book = &lib[i];
    while (book != NULL) {
        price+=book->price;
        book = book->nextedition;
    }
    return price;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! Can you tell me how the members of lib are changed in my code please?

Comment: You're welcome.  Assuming that `lib` is a global variable, the line `lib[i]=*(lib[i].nextedition)` appears to change it.